# Prevent express-session from sending cookie from a particular route

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

Below is my node server where I am testing express session:

```
//all imports here

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    name: 'session',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secure: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie:{
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 10*60*1000
    }
}))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.session);
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
})

app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
   req.session.loggedIn=true;
   req.session.user="Gratis";
   res.send("successful");
}


app.get('/homepage',(req,res)=>{
if(!req.session.loggedIn) res.redirect('/');
    else{console.log(req.session);
    res.send(" Hello ");}
})

app.listen(3000);
```

The server us working fine, in the sense that on hitting the '/' route, exptress esnds a cookie "session" which is active for 10 mins. Means that the server would be able to track user for 10 mins right after the user hits '/' route. Now my question starts here:
Suppose user logs in after 7 minutes of hitting '/' route. Then `req.session.username` would be there in session for only 3 minutes cuzz 7 minutes would have already passed. So my question is, is there any way to prevent express from sending 'session' cookie only when user has hit '/login' route so that user is remebered for 10 mins.

I could thought of only sending custom cookie using `res.cookie` but it would destroy the purpose of express-session cuzz we don't have to handle cookies manually.

Thank You!!

Comment: On every new request, isn't the cookie renewed for 10 minutes again.